# Copying person/identity tag of photo to traditional tag

Tags: windows-photo-gallery

I just started using Windows Live Photo Gallery and tagged about 400 photos using the person (people) tag.  For photos without people in them or photos with people that I don't want to identify, I used the traditional tag.  So now I have a mixed bag.  When I view the gallery by person, I get a lot of "not tagged" photos when, in reality, I have them tagged the way I want them.  Same thing when I view by the traditional tag.  If I had it to do over again, I would have just stuck with the traditional tag and listed the people there.

Is there a batch way of copying the person tag values to the traditional tag so that I have one set of tags and can arrange / view the photos by the traditional tag and have it all covered?